# VideoView not looping video only on Galaxy s4

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, galaxy

In my application I use a VideoView to stream video files,and I make the VideoView loop videos using the MediaPlayer.setLooping(true).

Here is some of the code -

```
videoView.setVideoPath(url);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (shouldLoopVideo) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }

    videoView.start();
}
 });
```

This code is working perfectly for all devices but the Galaxy s4 android 4.2.2 I tested on many devices, and many android versions, but the only ones that fail are the galaxy s4.

The device will play the video once, and stop (After calling the onCompletion listener).

Comment: see this link http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=249871&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug of Android 4.4.2. 
My workaround:

```
private String mVideoPath;
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mVideoPath = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.backvideo;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoBackground);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoPath));
    mVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);


    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoPath));
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });

    mVideoView.start();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mVideoView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoPath));
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

Comment: This work around is working ,
Set Looping was also not working on Oreo devices i.e Nexus 6P , Galaxy Note 8.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. Works on other devices, but not on Galaxy S4.

Is there some known solution for this problem.

My current workaround is to call setVideoPath() in onCompletion() which doesn't seams to be right for me.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code which work from android J to android O device

```
  VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);
        vv.setZOrderOnTop(true);

        try {
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vv);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(_video_link);
            vv.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            vv.setVideoURI(uri);
            vv.seekTo(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setLooping(true);
                vv.start();

            }
        });
        vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                vv.resume();
            }
        });
```